# In wordpress menu remove hover function from menu-item and replace it with click function

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

on my wordpress site i have a menu-item which opens a dropdown-menu on hover. I want like to disable the hover-function and replace it with a click-function.

My website is http://lab.tech-wave.de/efg. The specific menu-element is #menu-item-11

Answer (score 0):

Disable hover by adding `nav li#menu-item-11:hover>ul {display: none;}` to bottom of your .css file.

Add class to element on click `$("#menu-item-11").toogleClass("dropped-menu-item");` (function of third party library jQuery) and add style (also to the end of your .css file) to display drop down `nav li#menu-item-11.dropped-menu-item:hover>ul {display: block;}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Everytime i add your code below, i get this error:

TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$` symbol in javascript